# emacs shell could not process % character

Tags: shell, emacs

in emacs shell, when I type command "echo %", emacs will dead, when i cancel the command, the *Message* show error below:

```
comint-simple-send-around: Format string ends in middle of format specifier
```

I debug the error, because Emacs use `format` function, `%%` could work for `%`, but still send shell with `%%` character.

and below is the definition:

```
(defun comint-simple-send-around (simle-function proc string)
  (dolist (item name-variable-map)
    (let ((name (car item))
          (value (symbol-value (cdr item))))
      (setq string (replace-regexp-in-string name value string))
      ))
  (message string)
  (funcall simle-function proc string)
  )
(advice-add #'comint-simple-send :around #'comint-simple-send-around)
```

Comment: `M-x eshell` or `M-x shell` ?  In either case, I cannot replicate that problem.   Please tell us what `M-x emacs-version` says, and provide a recipe starting from `emacs -Q` to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Drew, thanks for your reply, i use shell, not eshell. version: "GNU Emacs 25.3.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2017-09-13" it is weird, emacs -Q works fine. when is start without "-Q" option, the message is "comint-simple-send-around: Format string ends in middle of format specifier" and i update the definition and setting in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in your custom code, where you're doing this:

`(message string)`

Where `string` is obviously evaluating to an *invalid* format string.

> `(message FORMAT-STRING &rest ARGS)`
>   ...
>   The first argument is a format control string, and the rest are data
>   to be formatted under control of the string.  Percent sign (%), grave
>   accent (`) and apostrophe (') are special in the format; see
>   `format-message' for details.  **To display STRING without special
>   treatment, use `(message "%s" STRING)`.**